# Force a browser to save file as after clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Is it possible to initiate a download prompt in the browser for recognized MIME types using only JavaScript (client-side approach)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763505/force-file-download-of-recognized-mime-types-using-only-javascript-almost-figur)

Is there a way to force a browser with a JavaScript routine to save a file as ("save as") after clicking a link? I need for images to be downloaded directly by default and not rendered by the browser.

Comment: You need to do that in the server.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You could use the HTML5 download attribute like so:

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to download</a>
```

This opens a "save as" dialog regardless of file type without taking you away from the page.

Comment: My current understanding is that this attribute is only recognized and honored in Google Chrome.

Comment: Does it degrade gracefully for those browsers that do not support it yet?

Comment: @JacksonHenley It links to the resource basically just ignoring the download attribute.  Check out this fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/GTCfy/  I've also verified it.  *It does not work in the latest versions of Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, or Safari.*  All others are untested.  *It does work in Google Chrome*.

Comment: A note here, I tried to [click the link with JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uMwqc/), but just like what I expected, it won't work.

Comment: try $("a")[0].click() to access the DOMs click, as opposed to jQuery's, it works

Comment: @Austin - Woot! [It does](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uMwqc/2/)!

Comment: These days this works in Firefox and Opera as well. See http://caniuse.com/download for exact coverage.

Comment: Not fool proof but simple and effective in most cases :) 
See here for current browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download

Comment: This does not work for me. (Safari 4.0.6)

Comment: It does not work in the latest versions of Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, or Safari. All others are untested. It does work in Google Chrome Date: `13 May 2017`

Comment: works for me in IE 11.0.96

Comment: @CodeCooker Working on Chromium 63 `18/01/2018`

Comment: @meyer1994 I did already mention that it is working on Chrome/Chromium LOL, Doesn't make sense to mention about this after some months!

Comment: The specification doesn't mention "save-as dialog", and so the action depends on the file-type. For instance, I have not yet found a way to force a save-as dialog for TXT and XML files. Instead, the browsers try to display the content in another tab.

Answer (score 15):

If you control the server, then you should set it up to send a Content-Disposition: attachment header for the files you wish to be downloaded (e.g. you can do this in an .htaccess file to make all .jpegs in a particular directory).