# How to add a button over image

Tags: html, css, button, jekyll

Hope you're all staying safe during these strange times!

**How do you a place a button over an image (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aATMg.jpg))?**

I'm using Visual Studio, Jekyll and Github.

I've tried copy and pasting this exact [coding](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp) into Visual Studio, but it turned out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4keN.png).

No matter what I do with the CSS, I can't move the button up onto the image.

I was hoping to ask you guys, because I'm totally lost.

Thanks so much everyone!

-- Complete newbie at coding

Comment: You can find a similar solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030184/clickable-image-button

Answer (score 0):

You can put it as a child of the picture container, and then absolutely position it.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 25vh;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: 3px dotted black;
}

.btn-group {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="btn1">Request Proposal</button>
  <button id="btn2">Learn More</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Joel for getting back to me :)  

I put your code in, but the buttons still can't move.   

I tried adjusting the absolute position to 100px, but the buttons remain in the same place. Please see here for screenshots:  

https://imgur.com/a/MfmdBVc  

Please let me know what I can do :)   

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't move?' I just used static values for the position. I can easily make it scalar and it'll all move around accordingly.

Comment: What  I mean is that when I change the values (see here - https://imgur.com/a/MTMNcJ3 ), the button still remains in the same place (which is below the background image). See here for what it looks like: imgur.com/a/MfmdBVc. No matter how I change the numbers in the coding, the buttons don't move up onto the image.

Comment: Did you see the HTML markup I used? The button group has to be a child element of the container in order to absolutely position itself relative to the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code in a code snippet or fiddle? Joel's answer should do the trick so it is something going wrong in your code. Check both the image and the button elements are within a container div and that the position properties of both elements are correct -
position: relative (for the container div)
position: absolute (for the button)
You can then play around with the position of the button with top/bottom and left/right properties.