# Force a link to open a "Save link as" dialog

Tags: html, web, download

Similar, but not quite this one:
[Force a browser to save file as after clicking link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link)

I don't just want to make the file download rather than render (the back end is already doing that with "Content-Disposition: attachment" header.  But we want our internal website users to click the link and get the dialog that lets them choose what directory to load the file to.  This, as opposed to the natural state of things where a non-right-click just downloads directly to the users' downloads folder.

Comment: Also, want to not be using any plugins.  Can't use the Adobe Flash ones out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and without any plugins, I think it is almost impossible. The only way you can do that would require you to verify the browser and for some browser like Chrome (due the spec http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html ) you can do that.