# a link - force Chrome to save file instead of opening

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to force a Chrome (and maybe other browsers) to save "mpg" file link instead of trying to open it in build-in media player via html code (and not changing settings of the browser)? I could do that via PHP with additional headers, but those files are really huge sometimes, so sending them via php wouldn't be too wise.

Before getting millions of `-1s`, just wanted to say that I know this is really simple question, but couldn't find an answer anywhere. Maybe it's just impossible?

Comment: Ignore me, I was confusing LINK element with A HREF; there seems to be a solution with HTML 5. Check, it may be duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link

Comment: @DaneBalia Thank you, `download` attribute worked. You may add an answer if you want, and I will accept it. I won't remove this question, as I couldn't find that answer myself, so even if it is a duplicate, may help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a solution with HTML 5 (download attribute):

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Download Now</a>
```