# save a file when clicked on the hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let's say I have two links to same file called `hello.avi`

```
<a href="/example.com/hello.avi">Play Movie</a>
```

and

```
<a href="/site.com/hello.avi">Download Movie</a>
```

when the user clicks the second link, how can I make the file to be prompted for a download, instead of opening the `hello.avi` file

Comment: did you tried "download" attribute in <a> tag?

Comment: <a href="/site.com/hello.avi" download="/site.com/hello.avi">Download</a>   if you are using html5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link  check this link

Comment: Beware that the download attribute is not understood on **Internet Explorer** nor **Safari** (source : [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)).

Comment: Beware it is also an attribute introduced in HTML5. So you have to be using HTML5 But if @Zeratops is correct then its a useless attribute anyway

Comment: possible dublicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link

Comment: @RiggsFolly here is another website that confirm the fact that this attribute is not compliant in IE/Safari : [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

Answer (score 2):

You can add [Download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute to your anchor tag as following

```
<a href="/site.com/hello.avi" download>Download Movie</a>
```

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link

Answer (score 0):

Download file when clicking on the link (instead of navigating to the file):

```
<a href="test.avi" download>Click here</a>
```

Download file and rename it to mytextdocument.avi:

```
<a href="test.avi" download="mytextdocument">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/images/your-picture.jpg" download>
```

You should google your question before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<a href="/example.com/hello.mp4" download>Download Movie</a>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.