# Download not starting on Firefox with download attribute of a tag

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I just checked some SO post they described `<a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to download</a>` is working almost every browser, Yes but not with Firefox. I tried with Chrome and Edge working perfectly but not with Firefox. how can i solve this any idea would be appreciated Thank you

N:B: I followed this link but no luck [Javascript-Force Browser to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and found the best answer. You can trigger a download by using the new HTML5 download attribute.

Where :
    **path_to_file** is either an absolute or relative path,
    **proposed_file_name** the filename to save to (can be blank, then defaults to the actual filename).

```
<a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: add /filename also in href

Comment: Nup !! No Luck.