# HTML <audio> source download with separated button

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I have audio Element Here

```
<audio controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="mp3FileName" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

with source "mp3FileName" I have separate download button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="mp3FileName" download>Download audio here</a>
```

but when I click it it just opens _blank audio source just like that

[image: audio when clicked download button]

I want to instant download when button is clicked. how can it be done?

Thanks for answers and sorry Guys I forgot that it's written on VueJs
Like That

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" :href="mp3FileName" download>Download audio here</a>
```

reason why it is used **:href** is because **"mp3FileName"** is from Vue Scripts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to initiate a download prompt in the browser for recognized MIME types using only JavaScript (client-side approach)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763505/is-it-possible-to-initiate-a-download-prompt-in-the-browser-for-recognized-mime)

Comment: Check if your file **extension** and **path** are correct

Comment: check this https://www.sanwebcorner.com/2017/07/auto-start-download-file-using.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772331/vue-html-js-how-to-download-a-file-to-browser-using-the-download-tag This Helped me kinda caused CORS issue.