# Open download screen inside of Opening inside Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform

I have this code, inside an MVC application which should download a video found inside a Google Bucket.

```
<a href="@item.fileUrl" download >Download</a>
```

Which should download the video normally and not open the video in the browser.

The link that is opening in the browser is this:

```
https://ff12ad44b930abcbf00ef65c56451119b990807d744137980f68851-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/my-bucket-name/o/neverTrimmed.mp4?jk=ARTXCFHVkKr14Xb3K8QDSMMnF44X-MeheMlWWV1HjFhrGlcTgQHjlFkZAAVjm3SQI3XU-JKJTpyLL6GiFH4JkiCQa_F25vG3XjFGLBaD8L_zs7mwTKEVX1isQ39jjFN-bAGlsemss1wb7yxzxGX1F9i07s713vIY2R_-H6k-bTAQ_AzkjKOnTWx88hGVYPdMezmgDYu1_riEu8C171orhw8jtcUrWT-tipmgutNScDhUjEoDejd1z65jvoLbh2OUjQTsX8Z6fCzuV1pWBOuGdka3D_QcgbauQ5rfMgxab80NWef5LvOxutfvEOZtdwBKMcs6NiYoxoWuMNF3a3IBE4lFyZ3_80xsSk_bRROJkgVnJmG-VhdR-WXF-jIVCBYQE3lUcomLlG9FLj7ALpZ56_qf-Jpk5iRDdAYekPCXZHSh5KjsJ3chcYbNvdH4b8_l-CP6S2pgGtyEryu4cCBH7y74F5WOHQgr67Bry4KvZV9S7nJOM5rXOOH-ct9OgVOpclD5RZ3txk8k6UljH3C5MtB5gyHMy64QXu9Ak6gnXfBl06PmZRkWIz9B383-GYYz0bIjdoL6niivEM9KVXgdAC504TJl4pxZ9WKXBreAp2hwF_PwNV3IuDG6Mtm8Rn_m59aNzAwz6brm4rsTG6P58oTbyNljiV0xnJi_83VBNRbdHG074cIZda0-kuYAyaKO3xKJ4pnsbvj2CwgXJtonk0ffRrbxZMo4eY7aurPSKILrPs7hcggDIkeoIPryzy15BFE_Mo7UHvAsbscEpC8eiOQcq78F6frlr-dgLuWnM0_oX5wqtArM2DrFY2Mz2HlobIxCY0o7Astyb3MFF8BPxd8KKjMcGPp0DNnwkaerpK_fAEo31XkXugw-ZvBVU1JSQCGGERzWAXojPsMYscFIi3JoFFbeoO9qXZYtuYIVt9_hmdj0dSHNOYYR6JWFDSrPx4k7NE79FyAiEV8vxpaY3bWlY5-iauU-uk56bhRyJibsZY4J0ZLhyyGRHTOX648pvTtXqqkwFBuX-0b-PgiFtg62dZ7w5oTr7_MeGrgLRdnslxOt40VN9EcpMhGpJ4oocwH73q__F6Czni8rRfbIfKm5KCbXXTOYweWXcKjdPqPQLhqw7c0DZGSk16TDrz2C4VRCa19Xadpky_wKdG1L0SJi7mX8KAlTS04&isca=1
```

The video inside the bucket is saved as

```
neverTrimmed.mp4
```

Can anyone think of a fix or at least a reason this is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to initiate a download prompt in the browser for recognized MIME types using only JavaScript (client-side approach)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763505/is-it-possible-to-initiate-a-download-prompt-in-the-browser-for-recognized-mime)